# of functions to be used while estimating the bounds of an integrals?

Tags: definite-integrals, estimation

I was asked to find the bounds of the integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2-x^3}}$$

that is . if

$\alpha \leq\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2-x^3}}\leq\beta$
I have to find $({\alpha}, {\beta)}$

that is
so to do this, my book wrote:-
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \leq \int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2-x^3}} \leq \int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-2x^2}}$$

however, these bounds seem arbitrary.

How to select bounds for such problems?

Comment: "Find *the* bounds" of a number has no meaning. What was the *exact* question you were asked?

Comment: The inequalities should be in the opposite order.

Comment: There are many bounding functions. Maybe they were arbitrary.

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Careful: $\int \frac{1}{f(x)}\, dx$ is not generally equal to $\frac{1}{\int f(x)\, dx}$. Which are they?

Comment: I suspect that the exercise involves finding bounds on the value of$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-x^2-x^3}}$ by bounding it between two definite integrals which can be solved using an $\arcsin$ substitution, and that the integrals written in the inequality are written incorrectly.

Comment: oh yes, typo@aschepler, I corrected it

Comment: Ah, now I see that the integrals have been corrected.

Comment: It’s arbitrary, so you take what’s convenient. Bounding by removing the $x^2$ term is also possible, but the integral would be much harder to evaluate

Comment: @FShrike, I see, thanks!

Comment: A simpler answer is to note that on $[0,1], 0 \le \frac 1{\sqrt{4 - x^2 -x^3}} \le \frac 12$ and thus $0 \le \int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{4 - x^2 -x^3}} \le \frac 12$. As Anne Bauval indicates, there is no such thing as "the" bounds on a number. Any bounds other than the number itself can be improved. My bounds will be less tight than those obtained by calculating the left and right integrations in the book's inequality. When finding bounds, there are two questions to be asked: "what do I need these bounds for"? This will tell you how tight they have to be. And "what can I calculate"?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, thanks a lot!